# Extreme point of unit balls, over $\mathbb C$

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, continuity, banach-spaces, lp-spaces

I've been trying to determine what are the extreme point of the unit balls of $\ell^1$ and $\mathcal{C}[0,1]$.

I think that I cracked the real case (I got for $\ell^1$: $\{e_n\}_{n\in \mathbb N}\bigcup\{−e_n\}_{n \in \mathbb N}$, and for $\mathcal{C}[0,1]$ the constant functions $f=1$ and $f=−1$).

I had a little trouble figuring out what should be the answer in case the field is $\mathbb{C}$. I think it should be (for $\ell^1$) all the $\{e_n\}_{n\in \mathbb N}\bigcup\{−e_n\}_{n \in \mathbb N}\bigcup\{ie_n\}_{n\in \mathbb N}\bigcup\{−ie_n\}_{n \in \mathbb N}$, and (for $\mathcal{C}[0,1]$) the functions $f=1,f=−1,f=i,f=−i$. But I can also see it go to (for $\ell^1$) all the $\{ae_n:|a|=1\}$, and (for $\mathcal{C}[0,1]$ all the constant functions $f=a$ with $|a|=1$.

I would like some guidness if possible. Knowing the right answer could help, as well as the intuition behind and maybe some tips on how to get there. Thanks!!

Comment: Thanks. Lets see then. the disk of $\mathbb C$ should be all extreme points of the ball. The extreme points of any n-gon would be the n vertex.

This logic would get me that the extreme of $C[0,1]$ would be the constant functions with $|a|=1$, right? What about $\ell^1$? Gotta think some more

Comment: No, it's a bit more complicated, the closed unit ball of $C[0,1]$ has non-constant extreme points. Precisely what are the extreme points of $\{ z \in\mathbb{C} : \lvert z\rvert \leqslant 1\}$?

Comment: I think it is $\{z\in \mathbb C : |z|=1\}$

Comment: That looks very reasonable. Try proving it.

Comment: After that, try looking at the extreme points of the unit ball of $C[0,1]$ from the other end first. If $f,g\in C[0,1]$ with $\lVert f\rVert,\lVert g\rVert \leqslant 1$ and $f\neq g$, what can you say about $h = \frac{1}{2}(f+g)$ beyond that $\lVert h\rVert \leqslant 1$?

Comment: well, say you have $x=a+bi$ with $|x|<1$ - it's easy to see it cannot be an extreme point since (without loss of generality) $a<1$ and therefore $x+tv \in D$ for $t\in(-1,1)$ and $v=(1-|a|)/2$. in case $|x|=1$, I'll get for any $v\not=0$ that $|x+tv|=((a+\Re(v))^2+(b+\Im(v)^2))^{1/2}>1$

Comment: That's right so far. And why are all points on the unit circle extreme points?

Comment: Because I just proved that they are not an interior point of any line. (this is the definition I'm working with / got in class)

Comment: Oh, sorry, overlooked that part. So on to $C[0,1]$, in the situation above, what do you know about $h$?

Comment: That there is $x_0\in [0,1]$ in which $|h(x_0)|<1$?

Comment: Right. So every non-extreme point has $\lvert f(x)\rvert < 1$ for some $x$. Thus the candidates for extreme points are?

Comment: The candidates are the continuous functions with $|f(x)|=1$ for all $x\in[0,1]$. Now I believe that they are all indeed extreme, and the proof should be very similar to the proof we first gave to the disk of $\mathbb C$. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, but I have made a tactical mistake. What we have already proved is that every $f$ with $\lvert f\rvert \equiv 1$ is an extreme point, what is missing is that these are all.

Comment: Actually in my mind the harder part was to show that every $|f|=1$ is extreme was the harder part. showing that they are all would be similar to the real case (I'll have a neighborhood in which $|f|<1$ and take a continuous function tiny enough that I could add and still be in the ball). Thanks!!

Do you have a recommendation for $\ell^1$? After this discussion I believe that the answer would be $ae_n$ for $|a|=1$, $n\in \mathbb N$. Am I right?

Thanks a lot!!!!

Comment: @DanielFischer: In case you didn't see my last comment (no rush tho lawl, you helped a lot. thanks again)

Comment: Why isn't the answer accepted? Have you figured out your question?

Answer (score 0):

What are the extreme points of $D = \{z \in \mathbb{C} : |z| \leq 1\}$?

If $f \in C([0,1],\mathbb{C})$ has $f(x)$ an extreme point in $D$, and $f(x) = tg(x) + (1-t)h(x)$, what can we say about $g(x)$ and $h(x)$?

Now what if $f(x)$ is an extreme point in $D$ for every $x \in [0,1]$?